# Did I stress the words correctly in this sentence?

Tags: american-english, pronunciation

I have this sentence: "Keep your voice down!"
I'm not sure how native speakers pronounce it, but I would put a bit of stress on "Keep" and more stress on "voice"

"2Keep your 1voice down!".

I don't think "down" needs any stress but I'm curious about your opinions too.

Comment: Context, context. *"KEEP YOUR VOICE DOWN!". "But I'm not shouting. You should keep **your** voice down!"*

Comment: You are correct, but you use the phrase for the second time, when the first speaker already said it. It makes sense to use "your" for the second time.

My context is this: When someone is yelling, I just want to say: KEEP your VOICE down and I want to be the first who say this. I hear stress on KEEP and VOICE, but I may be wrong.

Comment: I've no mechanism for searching for examples, but obviously it's perfectly possible (and can indeed be more "natural" in some contexts) to put the primary stress on ***DOWN***. And although it might be a bit more contrived, there will also be contexts where the primary stress can reasonably go on ***KEEP***. The exact position and level of stress can vary for practically *any* utterance.

Comment: But I think only children pronounce DOWN with a stress and sound kind of annoying to adults.

Comment: If you think stressing ***DOWN*** is exclusively a feature of childish (incompetent speaker?) usage, all I can say is I think that's a matter of opinion (yours, which I think is *wrong*). So after due consideration I think the question itself is Primarily Opinion-based.

Comment: I didn't say they are incompetent speakers. I just asked an opinion from a native American speaker. If you pronounce the phrase in a normal context, you should have an idea which word is emphasized, but people like to complicate things. It's true that any word can be stressed to give it emphasis, but there is a default unemphatic accent which is used most often.

Comment: I'll bug out then, since I'm not a native *American* speaker.

Comment: "*Keep* your voice down." "Keep *your* voice down.""Keep your *voice* down.""Keep your voice *down*." ... Possible.

Comment: @Zoltan: ***What is a "normal context"?*** I would stress this sentence differently when somebody is yelling, and when we're entering a library and I'm reminding somebody we need to be quiet. Both of these contexts seem perfectly normal to me.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: I don't think there's any difference here between BrE and AmE.

Comment: @Peter: I never seriously thought there would be - I was just reacting to OP's explicit reference to a native *American* speaker. I assume you'd have no problem being identified as a native *English* speaker (regardless of your nationality, you speak English), but it doesn't quite work for me the other way around. I feel it "marginalises" us Brits (which is unreasonable considering we graciously "lent" you our language in the first place! :) Anyway, I like your "when in a library" context for somewhere I'd be more likely to stress ***down***.

Comment: Yes, I think that's the correct most neutral stress.  If the speaker were adopting a strongly admonitory or scolding tone, primary stress could go on "down".

Comment: I think that in practice, I would almost always leave "down" unstressed, and put the primary stress on "voice". This includes both sentences of Peter Shor's below. I am an American, so maybe there is an actual trans-atlantic difference here. Or it might just be a matter of personal idiolects, or different definitions of "stress".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Stress in sentences in English often indicates the shade of meaning the speaker wishes to convey. In this case, there is ***not*** a unique way to say this phrase.

> (2)Keep your (1)voice down:

What you'd use 
when reminding somebody they will 
have to speak softly (say, they're going into
an animal shelter where speaking too loudly will
agitate the animals).

> (2)Keep your voice (1)down:

You're speaking too loudly right now. Please fix it.

You can even come up with contexts in which you'd stess *your*, but they seem relatively contrived to me.